# Is there a way to query 135 distinct tables in one single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our database, we have 135 tables that have a column named EquipmentId. I need to query each of those tables to determine if any of the them have an EquipmentId equal to a certain value. Any way to do this in a single query, instead of 135 separate queries?

Thanks very much.

Comment: If there is a way to do this in a signle query, I would LOVE to see it.  I think that this is a very good question.  I had to do this once and approached the problem by writing an app to handle it.  The app queried SysObjects, I believe, to get the names of tables with this column name, and then looped through those tables for the individual queries.

Comment: Sounds to me like your database schema should be different for your particular requirements.

Comment: Could be that he, like me, was querying a database to an app written by a 3rd party.  I got my start as a developer by getting data out of other vendor's databases, and I still have to do that from time to time.

Comment: Do you have 135 tables each storing equipment objects? Or are these FK columns and want to check EXISTS before a DELETE, say? Don't want to make any assumptions here :-)

Comment: +1 @gbn: Exactly what I was thinking.  There's nothing wrong at first glance with a design having 135 tables with FK's to an equipment table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at either Dynamic SQL to generate queries to all of the tables and perhaps union the results, or using something like the undocumented [sp_MSforeachtable](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx) stored procedure.

```
sp_msforeachtable 'select * from ? where equipmentid = 5'
```

Comment: This will fail if at least one table in database does not have equipmentid column.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a query to build a query:

```
select  'union all select * from ' + name + 
             ' where EquipmentId = 42' + char(13) + char(10) 
from     sys.tables
```

Copy the result, strip the first `union all`, and run the query :)

Comment: You typed it up faster than me! Was gonna suggest the same :)

Comment: This one will fail if at least one table in database does not have equipmentid column.

Answer (score 1):

I would dump them into a temp table or something else similar:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Equip NVARCHAR(50))
sp_msforeachtable 'INSERT INTO #TempTable (Equip) SELECT Equip FROM ?'
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that not all the tables in the DB have EquipmentId column.
If this is a valid assumption then @whereand parameter of sp_msforeachtable would help to filter the tables.
The query bellow will show all table names that have specified EquipmentId.
Table name will be shown as many times as many rows from this table have the specified EquipmentId.

```
declare @EquipmentId int = 666

create table #Result (TableName sysname)

declare @command nvarchar(4000) = 
    'insert into #Result select ''?'' from ? where EquipmentId = ' + cast(@EquipmentId as varchar)

execute sp_msforeachtable
    @command1 = @command,
    @whereand = 'and o.id in (select object_id from sys.columns where name = ''EquipmentId'')'

select * 
from #Result 

drop table #Result
```

Comment: +1 This approach works better than mine. Didn't realize you could split out the where like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to go Dynamic SQL on this one - query the system tables for all the tables that have columns named EquipmentId, and build a dynamic SQL statement querying each table for the presence of that particular EquipmentId you need.

EDIT: @mellamokb's seems much easier - try that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using LEFT JOIN's. First we'll need a base table to hold the *certain values* of EquipmentID's we're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE #CertainValues
(
    EquipmentID int
)
INSERT INTO #CertainValues(EquipmentID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #CertainValues(EquipmentID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO #CertainValues(EquipmentID) VALUES (3)
```

We can then join the 135 known tables to this base table using their respective [EquipmentID] fields. To avoid cardinality issues (duplication) due to an [EquipmentID] appearing in multiple rows of one table, it's best to use a subquery to get counts per [EquipmentID] on each of the 135 tables.

```
SELECT
    CV.EquipmentID,
    ISNULL(T001.CNT, 0) AS T001,
    ISNULL(T002.CNT, 0) AS T002,
    ...
    ISNULL(T134.CNT, 0) AS T134,
    ISNULL(T135.CNT, 0) AS T135
FROM
    #CertainValues AS CV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EquipmentID, SUM(1) AS CNT FROM Table001 GROUP BY EquipmentID) AS T001 ON CV.EquipmentID = T001.EquipmentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EquipmentID, SUM(1) AS CNT FROM Table002 GROUP BY EquipmentID) AS T002 ON CV.EquipmentID = T002.EquipmentID
    ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EquipmentID, SUM(1) AS CNT FROM Table134 GROUP BY EquipmentID) AS T134 ON CV.EquipmentID = T134.EquipmentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EquipmentID, SUM(1) AS CNT FROM Table135 GROUP BY EquipmentID) AS T135 ON CV.EquipmentID = T135.EquipmentID
```

This also gives us a more meaningful resultset which shows the count of rows per table for each of the *certain values* we are looking for. Below is a sample resultset:

```
EquipmentID  T001  T002  ...  T134  T135
-----------  ----  ----  ...  ----  ----
          1     0     1  ...     2     3 
          2     3     2  ...     1     0 
          3     0     0  ...     0     0
```